# What's wrong with jQuery, .css and z-index - i.e. find the error in the following code?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What's wrong with this?

```
    $("#tag_square").appendTo('#edit-area img').css({ position: "relative", left: "100px", top: "10px", z-index: "2"});
```

Everything up to the z-index works perfectly. Once I include the Z-index though, I get an 'uncaught SyntaxError - Unexpected Token' in the Javascript console.

What gives?

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find it's the `-` in `z-index`. Try using camelCase to see if it makes a difference:

```
$("#tag_square").appendTo('#edit-area img').css({ position: "relative", left: "100px", top: "10px", zIndex: "2"});
```

Or simply quote the property name, either using single (`'z-index'`) or double (`"z-index"`) quotes.

Comment: Yep....that does it. Right before you posted, I tried it with double quotes around the "z-index" too, and that worked also. Go figure :| Thnx.

Comment: No worries, it's merely *one* of the foibles of JavaScript, there to catch the unwary =)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use dash in javascript variable names. Try changing `z-index` to a string (`'z-index'`)

Answer (score 1):

Try `"z-index": "2"`?